# How can I calculate the daily recommended % value of calcium based on the information I have?

Tags: nutrition, calcium

Essentially based on the calcium information I have on these brands of water bottles brands, how can I calculate the daily % value of calcium they give?

Fiji water = 17mg/L Calcium
Evian water = 78mg/L Calcium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For calcium it depends on age and gender, as shown in [this chart](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/in-depth/calcium-supplements/art-20047097):

[image]

So for a male aged 19-50, 1 liter of Fiji water would be:

```
17 / 1000 = .017, or 1.7% of the RDV
```

And 1 liter of Evian would be:

```
78 / 1000 = .078, or 7.8% of the RDV
```

In other words, if you're looking for calcium in bottled water, you're looking in the wrong place. It's the most expensive possible source of calcium you could choose and not a very good one.

As Mayo notes:

> Your body doesn't produce calcium, so you must get it through other
>   sources. Calcium can be found in a variety of foods, including:
>
> - Dairy products, such as cheese, milk and yogurt
> - Dark green leafy vegetables, such as broccoli and kale
> - Fish with edible soft bones, such as sardines and canned salmon
> - Calcium-fortified foods and beverages, such as soy products, cereal and
>     fruit juices, and milk substitutes
>
> To absorb calcium, your body also needs vitamin D. A few foods
>   naturally contain small amounts of vitamin D, such as canned salmon
>   with bones and egg yolks. You can also get vitamin D from fortified
>   foods and sun exposure. The RDA for vitamin D is 600 international
>   units (15 micrograms) a day for most adults.

Notice that they don't mention water.